# Dictionary initializing in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any way to refer to the dict keys in the initialization body **using one line and using dict keys "a" and "b"**

Example:

```
def func(a,b)
    return {"a":longComputation1(), "b":longComputation2(), sum_a_b:?????}
```

Please don't change semanthics of code. This just an example.

Comment: Just write 2, since you hardcoded 1 and 1..

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why not just: `a = longComputation1()  b = longComputation2()  return {"a":a, "b":b, "sum_a_b":a + b}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

This would have to be done over multiple lines:

```
def func():
    d = {"a": longComputation1(), 
         "b": longComputation2()}
    d.update(sum_a_b = d['a'] + d['b'])
    return d
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function parameters:

```
>>> def func(a, b):
...     return {"a": a, "b": b, "sum_a_b": a + b}
...
>>> func(1, 2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'sum_a_b': 3}
```

**UPDATE** Question changed after I posted the above code; Use jonrsharpe's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to create the dict and define the names of the keys for the sum in a key named sum:

```
def sum_dict(**kwargs):
    result = {}
    total = 0
    sum_keys = kwargs["sum"]
    del kwargs["sum"]

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        val = value()
        result[key] = val
        if key in sum_keys:
            total += val

    result["sum_" + "_".join(sum_keys)] = total

    return result

print(sum_dict(a=lambda: 3,b=lambda: 2,c=lambda: 14, sum=["a", "b"]))
# {'a': 3, 'c': 14, 'b': 2, 'sum_a_b': 5}
```

To access the keys from a not created dict is not possible.

Another way would be to create a own dict class.

Comment: I want to use keys "a" and "b" in calculating of sum_a_b inside of dictionary initialization body

Comment: OK, then look at jonrsharpe's answer

Comment: jonrsharpe's answer uses separate line for inserting sum_a_b but the question was about using values from key "a" and "b" inside of initalization body. It is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Edited my answer, but its only one line with a function defined before.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what the practical application of this is, but if you mean that the key is dynamically constructed at initialisation time from other keys already present in the dictionary:

```
d = {"a":longComputation1(), "b":longComputation2()}
d['_'.join(['sum'] + d.keys())] = sum(d.values())    # assumes that keys are strings

>>> d
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'sum_a_b': 30}    # assuming that longComputation1() == 10 and longComputation2() = 20
```

Sorry that it is not a single line (why the constraint??), but AFAIK you can't refer to the dict's keys during initialisation.

Comment: Yes the goal of the question is the refering to the dict's keys during initialisation. If the answer is 'it is not possible' ok let it be

Comment: @Andigor I think the answer is no then, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just because I got some code with 'dict initialization style' and I don't want to change semantic and in one place I should initialize dict's member only if two previous were inititialized. If it it is not possible I can use intermidiate variables

Comment: I thougth that there should be something like 'this' or 'self' inside